# crystal report parameter incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Two Crystal reports

1. CrystalReport1.rpt
2. employeemonthly.rpt

Call these reports  on signal aspx.net page.

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            if (rd.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                DateTime to = Convert.ToDateTime(sdate.Text);
                dbconnect a = new dbconnect();
                ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();
                    a.OpenConnection();
                    a.cmd = new SqlCommand("viewattandace_repoeting",a.con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    a.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    da.SelectCommand = a.cmd;
                    da.Fill(ds, "viewattandace_repoeting");
                    rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
                    rDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                    rDoc.SetParameterValue("date", to);
                    rDoc.SetParameterValue("depid", 1);
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rDoc;
                    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
                    a.CloseConnection();
                    CleartextBoxes(this);
            }
            else
                if (rd.SelectedValue == "2")
                sd = Convert.ToDateTime(m.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + "1" + "/" + yt.SelectedItem.Text);
                    ed = LastDayOfMonth(sd);
                    dbconnect a = new dbconnect();
                    using (ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument())
                    {
                        a.OpenConnection();
                  a.cmd = new SqlCommand("viewattandace_repoeting", a.con);
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        a.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        da.SelectCommand = a.cmd;
                        da.Fill(ds, "viewattandace_repoeting");
                        rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("employeemonthly.rpt"));
                        rDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("sdate", sd);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("edate", ed);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("depid", 1);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("email", eet.Text.Trim());
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rDoc;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
                        a.CloseConnection();
                    }                       
                }
        }
    }
```

view only one report at a time which dropdownlist selected index. 
Now problem is view only first time selected report . when i selected other report then show this "parameter incorrect".

For Example 
I selected  CrystalReport1 report  in dropdownlist and click button .Then report view ,then I selected   employeemonthly report  and click button then show this "parameter incorrect" and Vice versa.

Comment: The report you are creating when rd.SelectedValue=="2" has a using statement, but the report for rd.SelectedValue=="1" does not.

Comment: Could you annotate the code with details on what datatypes these parameters are within Crystal Reports?  There might be a datatype mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can solved this by add new CrystalReportViewer control*

```
     protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (rd.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            CrystalReportViewer2.Visible = false;

            yl.Visible = false;
            yt.Visible = false;



        }
        if (rd.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = false;


            sdate.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

**Button click code **

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {

            if (rd.SelectedValue == "1")

            {
                CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
                    DateTime to = Convert.ToDateTime(sdate.Text);
                    dbconnect a = new dbconnect();
                    ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();
                    a.OpenConnection();
                    a.cmd = new SqlCommand("viewattandace_repoeting", a.con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    a.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    da.SelectCommand = a.cmd;
                    da.Fill(ds, "viewattandace_repoeting");
                    rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
                    rDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                    rDoc.SetParameterValue("date", to);
                    rDoc.SetParameterValue("depid", 1);
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rDoc;
                    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                                  a.CloseConnection();




            }
            else
                if (rd.SelectedValue == "2")
                {
                    CrystalReportViewer2.Visible = true;
                    sd = Convert.ToDateTime(m.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + "1" + "/" + yt.SelectedItem.Text);
                    ed = LastDayOfMonth(sd);
                    dbconnect a = new dbconnect();

                    ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();

                        a.OpenConnection();
                        a.cmd = new SqlCommand("viewattandace_repoeting", a.con);
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        a.cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        da.SelectCommand = a.cmd;
                        da.Fill(ds, "viewattandace_repoeting");
                        rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("employeemonthly.rpt"));
                        rDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("sdate", sd);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("edate", ed);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("depid", 1);
                        rDoc.SetParameterValue("email", eet.Text.Trim());
                        CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = rDoc;
                        CrystalReportViewer2.DataBind();
                        CrystalReportViewer2.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                        a.CloseConnection();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Please change if part of you code to

```
ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument())
```

as you have it in else part

Comment: can you please set a break point at   if (rd.SelectedValue == "1")
and make sure that Selected Value changes. If -yes then on ReportDocument  after  rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath... do rDoc.ReportParameters.Clear()

Comment: I can solved this by add new  CrystalReportViewer. thanx  for help .

Comment: Or just by setting CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null; and then provide the correct source :-)

Comment: i also try this but still not working . then i add new control.